# Iterating with ggsave and ggplot2

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I have a folder containing csv files. I am iterating over these csv files and creating one plot per csv file. I can do this via:

```
setwd("/myfiles/folder")
filenames = dir(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) { 
  tmp <-read.csv(filenames[i]); 
  print(ggplot(aes(x = count, y = time), data = tmp) + geom_point(aes(color = id)) 
      + geom_smooth(aes(color = id), method= "lm", se = F, formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)) 
      + ggtitle("Title") + labs(x="Count)",y="Time")+ggsave(file="ID_.jpeg"))
}
```

However, as you would expect this only creates one .jpeg file and thus it is overwritten each time and I am left with the final plot saved.

I have tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) { 
  tmp <-read.csv(filenames[i]); 
  print(ggplot(aes(x = count, y = time), data = tmp) + geom_point(aes(color = id)) 
       + geom_smooth(aes(color = id), method= "lm", se = F, formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)) 
       + ggtitle("Title") + labs(x="Count)",y="Time")+ggsave(file="ID"+id+".jpeg"))
}
```

But this results in:

> Error in regexpr("\.([[:alnum:]]+)$", x) : object 'id' not found

Why is the `id` not recognised by ggsave when it is previously (for the `geom_plot` item)?

Comment: String concatenation is not done with `+` in R, use `paste()`. For example: `ggsave(file=paste0("ID", ID, ".jpeg"))`. Also, where is "ID" coming from? did you mean lower-case `id`? You need to choose just one value for the file name.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question - I did mean `id` and not `ID`. `id` comes from the csv file, it is a column header. It is still saying `object 'id' not found`.  The data source `temp` is specified at the start for `ggplot`

Comment: Well, ggsave does not read data from the plot. If you want to get a value from tmp, you will need to be explicit i.e. `tmp$id`. But remember each row of tmp will have its own I'd value, you can take the first if you like with `tmp$id[1]`

Comment: Part of the problem here may be stylistic; it may be possible to include `ggsave()` by simply adding to the end of the plot object, but I've honestly never seen that done before (and I've seen _lots_ of ggplot2 code). Normally, one would create a plot objects and pass that to `ggsave` in a separate line.

Comment: @joran I think "adding" ggsave is very misleading; it's equivalent to doing `qplot() + NULL` followed by `ggsave(filename)`, i.e it appears to work because of two incidental side-effects: i) `ggsave()` has no return value, and no class so `ggplot2:::add_ggplot` is happy doing nothing with it; ii) `ggsave()` saves the latest plot displayed if none is passed explicitly, which works here (interactive session), but should not be confused with `qplot() %>% ggsave(file="test.pdf")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
for (ii in seq_along(filenames)) { 

  tmp <- read.csv(filenames[ii])

  p <- ggplot(aes(x = count, y = time), data = tmp) + 
          geom_point(aes(color = id)) + 
          geom_smooth(aes(color = id), method= "lm", se = F, 
                     formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)) + 
          ggtitle("Title") + 
          labs(x="Count)",y="Time")

  ggsave(file=paste0("ID", ii, ".png"), p)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in ggplot you provide data (in your case it is tmp) which has a column ID). While in ggsave it doesn't ask for data, so when you give a column name ID, ggsave doesn't know what to do with it.

What I suggest is to use i (your for iterator) in ggsave.

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) { 
tmp <-read.csv(filenames[i]); 
print(ggplot(aes(x = count, y = time), data = tmp) +   geom_point(aes(color = id)) 
   + geom_smooth(aes(color = id), method= "lm", se = F, formula=y ~ p  oly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)) 
   + ggtitle("Title") + labs(x="Count)",y="Time")+ggsave(file=paste0("ID",i,".jpeg"))
}
```